# .NET AutoFixture with complex child properties

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, autofixture

I am exploring using `AutoFixture` to handle creating some of our test data for unit tests. So far, it looks like this will save us quite a bit of code/maintenance. My only issue right now is that when creating an object, the complex children objects on it will not have the IDs hooked up appropriately. I'm trying to find a way to gracefully overcome this instead of just manually hooking up the IDs after the object is created. See example below:

```
public class Bar
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public string Name {get; set;}

    public Foo Foo {get; set;}

    public int FooId {get; set;}
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id {get; set}

    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

In this example, calling `var myBar = myFixture.Create<Bar>()` will populate all of the properties for both `Bar` and it's child property `Foo`. My issue here is that `myBar.FooId` will be different than the value for `myBar.Foo.Id`. The same issue exists for creating child collections. How can I overcome this without manually hooking up all of my IDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this :

```
var obj = myFixture
    .Build<Bar>()
    .Without(b => b.Foo)
    .Without(b => b.FooId)
    .Do(b =>
        {
            b.Foo = fixture.Create<Foo>();
            b.FooId = fixture.Create<int>();
            b.Foo.Id = b.FooId;
        })
    .Create()
```

Or you can check this [3rd package](https://github.com/ruskindantra/AutoFixture.AutoEntityFramework) which support the initialization of the navigation properties in EF for AutoFixture

> When the interceptor creates a new navigation object, it will check
>   for a matching int ____Id property. If present, it will set the Id
>   property of the new object so that foo.BarId == foo.Bar.Id. This also
>   applies when the name of the table is included in the Id property, so
>   foo.BarId == foo.Bar.BarId.

Comment: Your answer was very close. I needed to add `b.Foo = _fixture.Create<Foo>();` as the first line in the `.Do` block since `b.Foo.Id` gives a null reference exception otherwise. If you want to update your answer, I'll gladly accept it. For the record, I'll also be looking into the package you linked as it looks like I can accomplish something similar with a little less work/code involved. Thanks